# Parse, make promise sync

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

Their is a way to make Parse.Promise work sync?
I know that I can use chain of promises but I must make the promises that I receive from function work sync.

Or way to wait the Promise to finish like join for threads.

Comment: Promises can't make an asynchronous function synchronous, and you _wait for a promise to finish_ using `.then`

Comment: I cant see how .then is a way to wait to promise to finish. this only said what will happened when the promise finished.

Comment: maybe you can play with events ! trigger an event handled by a function before the end of your promise and ignore your promise

Comment: @Alon - yes, my description was a little flawed

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear so.

The nature of promises is that they work asynchronously, that's why they're useful. I can't really think of a situation where replacing promises with synchronous code would be beneficial, which is why it isn't an option. Have a read of [Parse's Promise documentation](https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#promises) for a bit more info on this.

Comment: I have written code and now I have to add one function that uses promises. And change all the code for this will take few hours..

Comment: Using promises over synchronous code is good practice. Writing functional code geared towards promises and running asynchronously from the start can save you a lot of headaches down the line.